# how to configure clang-format to ignore indentation on specific macros?

Tags: c++, clang-format

How do I configure clang-format to not change the indentation of macros inside a class definition?

```
class AA
{
    int a;
MACRO_B      // this is how I want the code to look like...
    int b;
};

class AA
{
    int a;
    MACRO_B      // this is how the code looks like after formating
    int b;
};
```